# C: Indexing pthreads with numbers 0 through n -1

Tags: c, pthreads

I've got a set of *n* threads that need to be numbered 0 to *n* - 1.

This does not work right.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MY_THREAD_COUNT 6

void *runner(void *param) {
    int id = *(int*)param;
    printf("Thread %d\n", id);
}

int main() {
    pthread_t thread_arr[MY_THREAD_COUNT];
    for (int i = 0; i < MY_THREAD_COUNT; i++)
        pthread_create(&thread_arr[i], NULL, runner, &i);
    for (int i = 0; i < MY_THREAD_COUNT; i++)
        pthread_join(thread_arr[i], NULL);
}
```

It results in output such as:

> Thread 2
> Thread 2
> Thread 3
> Thread 4
> Thread 5
> Thread 6

Creating a pointer for each thread's ID number *does* work right:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < MY_THREAD_COUNT; i++) {
        int *tmp = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *tmp = i;
        pthread_create(&thread_arr[i], NULL, runner, tmp);
    }
```

It results in output such as:

> Thread 0
> Thread 1
> Thread 2
> Thread 4
> Thread 5
> Thread 3

However, since it entails mallocing, leaking, yada yada, that's not my ideal solution.

Is there any way to get the id number from a function called inside of `runner()`? Something like `pthread_self()` but that would give serial numbers, 0 through *n* - 1?

Or — to open the question up more generally — what's the overall cleanest way to do this? If any approach is on the table, what do you think is best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results you see are because you have no guarantees when the created threads will run in relation to the `main` thread. You pass the address of `i` to `runner`. That's the same address each time, so whatever value is in `i` is what `runner` will see when it runs.  Even worse, the `for` loop could terminate before the thread runs (this explains your 6) ..  you're just getting lucky with that 6, `runner` is accessing memory out of scope when that happens.

One possible solution:

```c
#define MY_THREAD_COUNT 6

void *runner(void *param) {
    int id = *(int*)param;
    printf("Thread %d\n", id);
}

int main() {
    pthread_t thread_arr[MY_THREAD_COUNT];
    int threadArgs[MY_THREAD_COUNT];

    for (int i = 0; i < MY_THREAD_COUNT; i++)
    {
        threadArgs[i] = i;
        pthread_create(&thread_arr[i], NULL, runner, &(threadArgs[i]));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < MY_THREAD_COUNT; i++)
        pthread_join(thread_arr[i], NULL);
}
```

This will keep the arguments in scope for duration of run time.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this strategy earlier, but couldn't figure out how to pass it through the `void *` of `pthread_create()`.

Comment: @motaylormo ah ok, `&(threadArgs[i])` is an `int*` type, but no problems passing that to a function that accepts a `void*`. I like PaulSanders answer better than mine,, very clever, not sure I've seen that before in this context. He's casting each `i` to a `void*` and passing that to `runner`, where a copy gets made, then casting it back to `int`, no need for the array that I've got. Just be sure you do _not_ dereference the `i` pointers from his answer, they don't actually point to anything. In fact I wouldn't be surprised if some code analyzer tools flagged that.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
#define MY_THREAD_COUNT 6

void *runner(void *param) {
    int id = (int) param;
    printf("Thread %d\n", id);
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t thread_arr[MY_THREAD_COUNT];
    for (int i = 0; i < MY_THREAD_COUNT; i++)
        pthread_create(&thread_arr[i], NULL, runner, (void *) i);
    for (int i = 0; i < MY_THREAD_COUNT; i++)
        pthread_join(thread_arr[i], NULL);
}
```

And then you have no lifetime issues with the parameter passed to the child thread.

Comment: no guarantees `runner` will run for each thread with the correct value of `i`, or even worse, before the `for` loop terminates taking `i` out of scope.

Comment: @yano A _copy_ of `i` is passed to the child thread, so, no race condition

Comment: ohhh, right I see, sorry. You're just casting the value to a pointer then back to `int` .. my apologies.

Comment: @yano No worries, I have already committed my quota of boo boos for the day :)

Comment: @Paul Sanders - This throws up "warning: cast to/from different size" when I try to compile it. After doing a bit of reading, it appears the casts in your answer would have to be changed to `(void *)(intptr_t)i` and `(int)(intptr_t)param` in order to work?

Comment: Yes, that sounds better, please feel free to edit my answer.