# Race condition in C

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads, mutex

I have the following program (abbreviated) to count the number of times each letter appears in a file using threads:

```
#define N_LETTERS 26U

#define IS_LETTER(x) (x >= 'A' && x <= 'Z')
#define HASH(x) toupper(x) - 'A'

typedef unsigned int uint;

typedef struct {
    uint nt;
    uint nc;
    char filename[128];
} Args;

Args args = {0};
char *file_contents = NULL;
uint file_size;

uint chars_per_thread;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
uint letter_count[N_LETTERS] = {0};

void get_program_args(int argc, char **argv) {
    ...
}

uint read_file(char *filename, char **buffer) {
    ....

    return file_size;
}

void *count_letters(void *arg) {
    uint start = *((int *)arg);
    uint end = (start + chars_per_thread) >= file_size ? file_size : (start + chars_per_thread);
    uint count[N_LETTERS] = {0};

    for (uint i = start; i < end; i++) {
        char c = toupper(file_contents[i]);

        if (IS_LETTER(c)) {
            count[HASH(c)]++;
        }
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    for (int i = 0; i < N_LETTERS; i++) {
        letter_count[i] += count[i];
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    return NULL;
}

float letter_sum() {
    ...
    return sum;
}

void print_letter_count() {
...
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    uint chars_counted = 0;

    get_program_args(argc, argv);
    file_size = read_file(args.filename, &file_contents);

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);

    pthread_t *threads = malloc(args.nt * sizeof(pthread_t));
    if (threads == NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating memory. \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    chars_per_thread = (file_size / args.nt) > args.nc ? args.nc : (file_size / args.nt);

    while (chars_counted < file_size) {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.nt; i++) {
            uint start = chars_counted;

            if (start >= file_size)
                break;

            pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, count_letters, &start);

            chars_counted += chars_per_thread;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < args.nt; i++) {
            pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
        }
    }

    print_letter_count();

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    free(threads);
    free(file_contents); // free allocated memory

    return 0;
}
```

Every time i run my program using more than 1 thread i get a different answer, it seams like i have a race condition, but i cannot find it. Can someone help me?

I tried using a mutex_lock to fix it but it still has the same issue.

Comment: passing `&start` to each thread is trouble. `start` goes out of scope at the end of the `for` loop each iteration. Each thread needs it's own `start` and they to survive long enough for each thread to be able to use it. You might as well `malloc` each `start` when you do each thread, but there are other ways.

Comment: [this is a dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980690/c-indexing-pthreads-with-numbers-0-through-n-1/75980786#75980786) for the `start` problem, but there could be other issues beyond that.

Comment: Also, `uint start = *((int *)arg);` should be `uint start = *((uint*)arg);`

Comment: Side note: your `toupper()` does nothing, since it is only called when its argument already is an upper case letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As others have mentioned], the race condition is that `start` can change [faster] in `main`, than it can be retrieved in `count_letters`.

That is because we're passing a *pointer* to `start`.

---

There are [at least] two ways to solve this ...

1. Pass `start` *by value* [instead of by pointer].
2. Create a custom `struct` (e.g. `struct mytask`) that has all/many values needed and pass a pointer to it.

---

By value ...

In `main`, change:

```
pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, count_letters, &start);
```

Into:

```
pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, count_letters, (void *) (uintptr_t) start);
```

And, in `count_letters`, change:

```
uint start = *((int *) arg);
```

Into:

```
uint start = (uintptr_t) arg;
```

---

Because you're already doing `malloc` for an array of `pthread_t`, let's change this to a `struct`.

This is more general. In the above case, we can only pass *one* value. But, with a `struct` we can pass as many as we would like:

```
typedef struct {
    pthread_t tid;
    uint start;
    uint end;
    // more values [if we wish] ...
} mytask;

void *
count_letters(void *arg)
{
    mytask *tsk = arg;
    uint count[N_LETTERS] = { 0 };

    for (uint i = tsk->start; i < tsk->end; i++) {
        char c = toupper(file_contents[i]);

        if (IS_LETTER(c)) {
            count[HASH(c)]++;
        }
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    for (int i = 0; i < N_LETTERS; i++) {
        letter_count[i] += count[i];
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    return NULL;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    uint chars_counted = 0;

    mytask *threads = malloc(args.nt * sizeof(*threads));
    if (threads == NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating memory. \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // ...

    while (chars_counted < file_size) {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.nt; i++) {
            mytask *tsk = &threads[i];

            tsk->start = chars_counted;
            if (tsk->start >= file_size)
                break;

            tsk->end = (tsk->start + chars_per_thread) >= file_size ?
                file_size : (tsk->start + chars_per_thread);

            // add more values ...

            pthread_create(&tsk->tid, NULL, count_letters, tsk);

            chars_counted += chars_per_thread;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < args.nt; i++) {
            mytask *tsk = &threads[i];
            pthread_join(tsk->tid, NULL);
        }
    }

    // ...

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why @yano didn't make their comment an answer, but that's the problem. You pass a pointer to `start` to each thread when you start it, and then you go and change the value of `start` while that thread is trying to read it! You need an array of start values, and pass a pointer to that thread's own personal copy of its start that doesn't get changed.