# How do I use pthread_join() for multithreading?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have code that is supposed to iterate over an image, and I attempted to create threads to handle different parts of the code. However, I am not sure how to properly join them before exiting the function.

```
struct p_args{
    int end;
    int start;
    struct image *pic;
};

void par_thread(struct p_args *args){
    struct p_args* pthread_args = args;
    for (int i = pthread_args->start; i <= pthread_args->end; i++){
        pthread_args->pic->pixels[i] = grayscale(pthread_args->pic->pixels[i]); 
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
};

void grayscale_par(struct image *img, unsigned int n_threads){
    pthread_t t_id[n_threads];

    int tasks = (img->width * img->height);
    int remainder = tasks % n_threads;
    int d_tasks = ((tasks - remainder) / (n_threads-1));

    struct p_args *p_arguments = (struct p_args*)malloc(sizeof(struct p_args));
    p_arguments->end = d_tasks;
    p_arguments->start = 0;
    p_arguments->pic = img;
    


    for (int x = 0; x < n_threads - 1; x++){

        pthread_create(&t_id[x], NULL, (void*) par_thread, p_arguments);
        pthread_join(t_id[x], NULL);
        p_arguments->start += d_tasks;
        p_arguments->end = (p_arguments->start + d_tasks);
        
    }
    p_arguments->start = (tasks - remainder);
    p_arguments->end = (tasks);
    pthread_create(&t_id[n_threads-1], NULL, (void*) par_thread, p_arguments);

    // for (int i = 0; i < n_threads-1; i++){
    //     pthread_join(t_id[i], NULL);
    // }

    pthread_join(t_id[n_threads-1], NULL);

    free(p_arguments);
}
```

My initial attempt was the commented-out code, but that would result in some threads not being processed. It works as it is now but obviously is waiting on one thread to finish before beginning the next, which defeats the purpose of this project.

Comment: `pthread_join` blocks the calling thread until the specified thread finishes. Calling `pthread_create`, then `_join` in the same loop makes little sense, you'll get no parallel threads that way. `main` will create a thread, wait for it to finish, then create the next one, then wait for it to finish, etc. You want to create them all at once, then `_join` on them in another loop so they can all work in parallel. Not sure what you're trying to accomplish with `pthread_create(&t_id[n_threads-1]`, but take `_join` out of the first loop and uncomment the 2nd loop that `_join`s.

Comment: Maybe move the loop that `join`s directly under the loop that `create`s ... and if you just have one task to do after all the worker threads finish, probably best to just do it on the main thread instead of spawning a single worker thread and immediately `join`ing on it. Spawning threads isn't free.

Comment: You need an _array_ of `p_args`, not just a single instance. With a single instance you have the same issue as solved in my answer: [Race condition in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76211985/5382650)

Comment: Also, you probably want: `i <= pthread_args->end;` --> `i < pthread_args->end;` And, you want to special case calculation  of `end` for the _last_ thread [unless the number of data points is evenly divisible by `d_tasks` (i.e. `n_threads`)].

Comment: Thread start routine signature is `void *(*)(void *)`, not `void (*)(struct p_args *)`. Don't cast function pointers to `void *`.

Answer (score 0):

> My initial attempt was the commented-out code,

Your initial attempt *is* correct: you should have two separate loops -- one to start the threads, and another to join them after they are done processing.

> but that would result in some threads not being processed.

That's because there is a *separate* bug. As Craig Estey commented, you can't update a single `p_arguments` location and pass it to all the threads -- you don't know when they'll *actually* start.

You need an *array* of `p_arguments`, so each thread will get its own set of arguments.

```
    struct p_args *p_arguments = malloc(sizeof(struct p_args) * n_threads);
    ...
    for (int x = 0; x < n_threads - 1; x++){
        pthread_create(&t_id[x], NULL, par_thread, &p_arguments[x]);
```

P.S. Do read the comments -- you have other bugs to fix.

Also, you'll do well to use `i`, `j`, `k` for `int` variables and `x`, `y`, `z` etc. for doubles.

This tradition dates back to Fortran, but there is *no reason* to use `x` as an integer array index.